# Authentication with multiple Azure AD Instances Episerver

Tags: azure, adfs, episerver

We have been asked to provide Azure ADFS SSO capability for a customer. This is for a new Episerver CMS site version 11. The original request was to have just the one, which I was able to build no problem. The problems I'm having now is trying to  authenticate using two Azure Tenants. I came across this article  https://blogs.perficient.com/2021/01/22/episerver-authentication-with-multiple-azure-ad-instances/ and then also this one https://world.optimizely.com/forum/developer-forum/CMS/Thread-Container/2018/10/configuring-episerver-cms-to-use-2-different-adfs-environments/ - where there hasn't been any response... and dates back to  2018

This issue I'm getting following David Lewis example is I' can't seem to hit the code set in the '`AppStartupServices.cs`'

This is my code:

```
private static readonly string tenant_1TenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant_1AzureAD:Tenant"];

    // <add key="AzureAD:ClientID" value="Client ID from Azure AD application" />
    private static readonly string tenant_1ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant_1AzureAD:ClientID"];

    private static readonly string tenant_1CommonAuthority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, tenant_1TenantId, "common/");

    // <add key="AzureAD:Tenant" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}" />
    private static readonly string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAD:Tenant"];

    // <add key="AzureAD:ClientID" value="Client ID from Azure AD application" />
    private static readonly string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAD:ClientID"];

    //<add key="AzureAD:RedirectUri" value="https://the logout post uri/" />
    private static readonly string azureRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAD:RedirectUri"];

    private static readonly string commonAuthority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, tenantId, "common/");

    const string logoutPath = "/Util/logout.aspx";

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions("tenant_1")
        {
            ClientId = tenant_1ClientId,
            Authority = tenant_1CommonAuthority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = azureRedirectUri,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role
            },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {
                    if (context.Exception.Message.Contains("IDX21323"))
                    {
                        context.SkipToNextMiddleware();
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Write(context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                },
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                {
                    // Here you can change the return uri based on multi sites
                    HandleMultiSiteReturnUrl(context);

                    // To avoid a redirect loop to the federation server send 403 
                    // when user is authenticated but does not have access
                    if (context.OwinContext.Response.StatusCode == 401 &&
                        context.OwinContext.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        context.OwinContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                        context.HandleResponse();
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                SecurityTokenValidated = (ctx) =>
                {
                    var redirectUri = new Uri(ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

                    if (redirectUri.IsAbsoluteUri)
                    {
                        ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri = redirectUri.PathAndQuery;
                    }
                    //Sync user and the roles to EPiServer in the background
                    ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISynchronizingUserService>().
                        SynchronizeAsync(ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Identity);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions("tenant_2")
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = commonAuthority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = azureRedirectUri,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role
            },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    context.Response.Write(context.Exception.Message);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                {
                    // Here you can change the return uri based on multi sites
                    HandleMultiSiteReturnUrl(context);

                    // To avoid a redirect loop to the federation server send 403 
                    // when user is authenticated but does not have access
                    if (context.OwinContext.Response.StatusCode == 401 &&
                        context.OwinContext.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        context.OwinContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                        context.HandleResponse();
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                SecurityTokenValidated = (ctx) =>
                {
                    var redirectUri = new Uri(ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

                    if (redirectUri.IsAbsoluteUri)
                    {
                        ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri = redirectUri.PathAndQuery;
                    }
                    //Sync user and the roles to EPiServer in the background
                    ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISynchronizingUserService>().
                        SynchronizeAsync(ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Identity);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });


        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
        app.Map(logoutPath, map =>
        {
            map.Run(ctx =>
            {
                ctx.Authentication.SignOut();
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            });
        });
    }
```

Global.ascx.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Adfs",
            "Adfs",
            new { controller = "AdfsController", action = "index" }
        );
```

In my web.config I have the following set

```
<authentication mode="None"/>
 
<membership>
        <providers>
            <clear/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
 
<episerver.framework createDatabaseSchema="true" updateDatabaseSchema="true">
    <securityEntity>
        <providers>
            <add name="SynchronizingProvider" type="EPiServer.Security.SynchronizingRolesSecurityEntityProvider, EPiServer"/>
        </providers>
    </securityEntity>
```

I've then created my own MVC login to then redirect to each Azure tenant

```
public class AdfsController : Controller
{
    // GET: Adfs
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var pageRouteHelper = EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IPageRouteHelper>();
        PageData currentPage = pageRouteHelper.Page;

        return View(currentPage);
    }

    public ActionResult AdfsLogin(string tenantContext, string returnUrl)
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = returnUrl ?? "/" }, tenantContext);
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
}
```

And then in my View

```
@{
using (Html.BeginForm("AdfsLogin", "Adfs", new {  ReturnUrl = "/episerver", tenantContext = "tenant_1" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <ol class="clearfix">
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="tenant 1" id="btnAd1" class="epi-button-child-item" />
        </li>
    </ol>
}
using (Html.BeginForm("AdfsLogin", "Adfs", new { ReturnUrl = "/episerver", tenantContext = "tenant_2" }))
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <ol class="clearfix">
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="tenant 2" id="btnAd2" class="epi-button-child-item" />
        </li>
    </ol>
}
```

Has anyone else had this problem? or know how to resolve it

Comment: "azure ad" or "adfs"?

Comment: We're attending to connect to Azure AD using our TenantId and Client ID - we need to be able to have two configured. I can get one instance working,  so if I click 'tenant 1' this however hits 'tenant_2' in the AppStartupServices.cs and even if I hit 'tenant 2 it still  hits 'tenant_2'. it doesn't seem to be getting set from the 'AdfsController' controller